# Указатель без *

Tags: c++, функции, указатели, ссылки, синтаксис

Можно записать функцию

```
void WNToV(Node* rootTree, std::vector<BYTE>* block, lu* writePos) {
    (*writePos) += sizeof(777);    
}
```

А можно ли записать так, чтобы вместо `(*writePos)` писать нормально `writePos`?

P.S. По идее, видел где-то, что вместо `*` в заголовке нужно `&` прописать, но не знаю, как точно.

Comment: В сигнатуре функции `lu* writePos` заменить на `lu &writePos`, если правильно помню. И это уже будет называться не указатель, а ссылка.

Comment: Понятия нормальности в этой среде могут быть диаметрально потивоположены (к  вопросу о "нормальности" использования ссылок)

Comment: @avp не соглашусь. Как говорил один мудрый мужик, нужно использовать только те средства, что нужны - та, где это необходимо. В данном случае городить огород с скобочками - плохая идея

Comment: Плохая идея это вообще использование ссылок. Видите в чужом коде из 100000 строк  `int x = 10; f(x);` а потом (если не посмотрели заранее на сигнатуру `f()`) удивляетесь, почему `x` стало 100.

Comment: @avp это да.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Читайте, что такое ссылки и передача аргументов по ссылке.

```
void WNToV(Node* rootTree, std::vector<BYTE>* block, lu& writePos) {
    writePos += sizeof(777);    
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, понял.